# Could not find opencv-related header file stitcher.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to use the [stitching mechanism](http://study.marearts.com/2013/11/opencv-stitching-example-stitcher-class.html) from OpenCV library in C++ but I don't see any `stitcher.hpp` file in the "opencv2" folder after OpenCV 3.0 installation. Where is it?

Comment: `opencv/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching.hpp` ?

Comment: @sergej Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Stitcher` class is declared in [`\modules\stitching\include\opencv2\stitching.hpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching.hpp).